# Como concatenar variável PHP com coluna MySQL?"

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
function retornaClientesDevedores ($mesReferencia, $dias) {

 require_once "PhpUtil.php"; 
 $PhpUtil = new PhpUtil();  

 $string = "SELECT idClientes, nome FROM clientes WHERE idClientes IN ( 
     SELECT idClientes FROM planosclientes WHERE idPlanosClientes IN (
     SELECT distinct(idPlanoClientes) FROM pagamentos WHERE mesReferencia NOT IN ('".$mesReferencia."') 
      ) and ".$PhpUtil->diferencaDatas(date('Y-m-d'), date('Y-m')."-diaVencimento'".)->days." > ".$dias."
      UNION
     SELECT idPlanosClientes FROM planosclientes WHERE idPlanosClientes NOT IN                                               (SELECT distinct(idPlanoClientes) FROM pagamentos)
                                             ) ";         
    }
```

Minha dificuldade é que tenho uma função que vem de uma classe. Essa função pede duas datas. Uma atual e outra que preciso pegar a data atual sem o dia, portanto `date('Y-m')` e concatenar com um campo `diaVencimento` da tabela para montar a data. Como fazer essa concatenação no PHP?

Comment: Oi, Carlos, "Ajuda com consulta" é um título que não significa nada... para atrair a atenção de programadores interessados em te ajudar, faça um título que descreva exatamente o problema.

Comment: Obrigado @brasofilo. Vou ficar mais atento!

Comment: O que é `\"-diaVencimento\"` ?? Eu desconheço esse tipo de atribuição a métodos, principalmente, concatenado com uma função `date()`.  Explique...

Comment: diaVencimento é um campo da tabela. Preciso pegar esse valor e concatenar com o resultado de date ('Y-m')

Comment: um titulo adequado seria "como concatenar variável php com coluna mysql?"

Comment: Obrigado Daniel!

Answer (score 5):

Para concatenar dois ou mais campos no MySQL utilize a função [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) da seguinte forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('".date('Y-m')."', '-', diaVencimento) AS data FROM pagamentos";
```

ou

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('".date('Y-m-')."', diaVencimento) AS data FROM pagamentos";
```

Aplique conforme sua necessidade.

Espero que ajude, abraços

Answer (score -1):

Pensando bem me parece que nem vou precisar disso.

Um Cliente tem um plano e se compromete a pagar todo dia '15' por exemplo. Então, no dia '7'$ por exemplo quero tirar a lista do mês.
Como só entra os que ainda não pagaram e que tem uma carência de 5 dias após a data, logo tria que fazer (diaHoje - DiaVencimento) o que dará (7-15 = -8) que é menor que os 5 dias de carência.

Na verdade é o seguinte

A função que estou usando é:

```
  function diferencaDatas ($dataInicio, $dataFim) {
$dataInicio = new DateTime($dataInicio);
$dataFim  = new DateTime($dataFim);
$diferencas = $dataInicio->diff($dataFim);

return $diferencas;
  }
```

Chamada:

```
$dataHoje = date('Y-m-d');
$dataVencimento = date('Y-m')."-dataVencimento ";

$diasDiferenca = diferencaDatas ($dataHoje , $dataVencimento ) ->days;
```

Saber quantos dias de diferença são.

Mas como a listagem será efetuada sempre dentro do mesmo mês, tanto  `$diaHoje` quanto o `$diaVencimento` ocorrerão no mesmo mês, logo não precisarei da função bastando fazer a simples diferença entre eles.

Estou certo em meu raciocínio?

Pois se eu vou tirar a listagem por exemplo no dia 25, o mês é 09. Logo, vou pegar a data da listagem (25) e tirar o dia do vencimento (caso ainda não tenha sido paga) se der até 5, esta no prazo, caso contrário, esta em débito.

classe corrigida.

```
<?php
 class Relatorios {

private $conexao;

public function __construct ($_conexao) { 
    $this->conexao = $_conexao;
}
/*
     //COMENTÁRIO DA FUNÇÃO ABAIXO
//SELECIONAR OS ID'S E OS NOMES DOS CLIENTES
$string = "SELECT idClientes, nome FROM clientes WHERE idClientes IN ( 
                   //SELECIONAR ID'S DOS CLIENTES QUE TEM PLANOS E QUE A DIA DE VENCIMENTO É MENOR QUE A O DIA ATUAL
SELECT idClientes FROM planosclientes WHERE idPlanosClientes IN (
   //MAS NÃO PAGARAM A PARCELA DO MES CORRENTE 
SELECT distinct(idPlanoClientes) FROM pagamentos WHERE mesReferencia NOT IN ('".$mesReferencia."') 
                  ) and DATEDIFF (curdate(), CONCAT('".date('Y-m')."','-', diaVencimento)) > ".$dias."
  //UNIÃO COM
UNION
    //SELECIONAR ID'S DOS CLIENTES QUE TEM PLANOS E QUE NÃO PAGARAM NENHUMA PARCELA
SELECT idPlanosClientes FROM planosclientes WHERE idPlanosClientes NOT IN                                               (SELECT distinct(idPlanoClientes) FROM pagamentos)
  ) ";         
*/

 function retornaClientesDevedores ($mesReferencia, $dias) {

$retorno = array();

$string = "SELECT DISTINCT(idClientes), nome FROM clientes WHERE idClientes IN ( 
              SELECT idClientes FROM planosclientes WHERE idPlanosClientes IN (
SELECT distinct(idPlanoClientes) FROM pagamentos WHERE mesReferencia NOT IN ('".$mesReferencia."') 
) and DATEDIFF (curdate(), CONCAT('".date('Y-m')."','-', diaVencimento)) > ".$dias."
UNION
SELECT idPlanosClientes FROM planosclientes WHERE idPlanosClientes NOT IN                                               (SELECT distinct(idPlanoClientes) FROM pagamentos)
  ) ORDER BY nome";        

$dados =  $this->conexao->query($string);   

if($dados->num_rows == 0) {
$retorno = null;
}
else {
$contador = 0;
while ( list ($idClientes, $nomeClientes) = $dados->fetch_row())   {
$retorno[$contador][0] = $idClientes;
$retorno[$contador][1] = $nomeClientes;
$contador++;
}
}

      return $retorno;
  }
}
?>
```